# Delphi Help Insight not avalaible if unit does not belong to project?

Tags: delphi, documentation, delphi-2009

I have a `unit` with `class` which is documented by /// tags and it works fine - Help Insight is creating a in-fly desrciption for given method in `class`.

However, this works fine **only** if given `unit` belongs to the project. It does not work if the `unit` is inside a separate package which is installed under Delphi and then used in other project. In such case I have no description window when I hover my mouse over function from documented class.

I've tried put given unit to the search paths and browsing paths of the IDE but it did not help.

Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Have you tried Castalia? It has a better system I think.

Comment: I had no idea that Castalia have support for such thing, thanks will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve this (and other similar problems with Delphi packages) is to add the Unit in question to the actual project in which it's being used (i.e. right click on the project and choose "Add..."), rather than adding it to the search path. So the same Unit ends up a member of multiple projects.

It's not ideal, but otherwise there is no point writing the xmldocs in the first place.

This works in D2010.